# TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined onEdit - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on the following code. I'm getting the following error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
> onEdit  @ Code.gs:6

Code:

```
function onEdit(event) {
// assumes source data in sheet named calls
// target sheet of move to named Completed
// getColumn with drop-downs is currently set to column 7 or F
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "Calls" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "CSR Transfer") {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CSR Transfer");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
}
```

Comment: Where is onEdit called? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @NathanChu google apps scripts (spreadsheets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation:**

This function is executed automatically when the user edits the sheet.

- You are not supposed to execute this manually as you do right now and hence you are getting an error.
- In particular, the block of code you have inside the if statement will be executed upon edits in column 7 (column G) in the sheet `Calls` and when the edited value is `CSR Transfer`.

**Code snippet:**

Take full advantage of the [event object](https://www.google.com/search?q=event%20object%20javascriptgoogle%20apps%20script&oq=event%20obje&aqs=chrome.1.69i59i457j69i59l2j69i57j0l2j69i60l2.2213j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

```
function onEdit(event) {
  const ss = event.source;
  const s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const r = event.range;
  if(s.getName() == "Calls" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "CSR Transfer") {
    const row = r.getRow();
    const numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CSR Transfer");
    const target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Make sure the code is saved, the sheet names: `Calls` and `CSR Transfer` exist and that you edit column `G` in `Calls` with the value `CSR Transfer`.